# Input Select File should not allows to override the previous one. is it possible?

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery

Drag and Drop file allows you to override the previous one - should this happen or should it say there's already a file in place? when select next new file.Is there any way to validate previous one file should not overridden.using jquery OR any other way.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

By using the below js and html code we can get confirmation from user that previously selected file. should be override or not.
HTML :

```
    <input name="importfile" id="importfile" value="" class="input-text file" type="file" data-validate="{required:true}" onClick="return alreadyFileExist(this); return false;" />
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <button type="submit" title="<?= __('Import') ?>" onclick="return SubmitFile(this.form)"  class="button orange-btn action primary"><span><span><?= __('Import') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
```

**CONFIRM PROMPT CODE :**

**for drag & drop we used drop event to prevent override by putting confirmation box.**

```
window.addEventListener("drop",function(e){
            var fileName = jQuery('#importfile').val();
            if (fileName) {
                var yes = confirm("file is already exists, would you like to override ??");
                if (yes == false) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }
        },false);

    function alreadyFileExist(object){
        if (object.value) {
            var yes = confirm("file is already exists, would you like to override ??");
            if (yes == false) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Form Submit :

```
function SubmitFile(frm)
{
    var fileName = jQuery('#importfile').val();
    var fileExt = '.' + fileName.split('.').pop();
    if(fileName && fileExt != ".csv")
    {
        if (jQuery('#importfile-error').length) {
            jQuery('#importfile-error').html('Only csv File is allowed.');
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```